# Exclude folder Intel XDK on build

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, intel-xdk, android-icons

I built my Android app with Intel-XDK, I chose an icon and splash screen in `Launch Icons and Splash Screen` tab, but the files should be in the source directory.

I want to exclude the folder with splash screen and icons images in source directory on build.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with our current build system. We are working on improvements to the build system that would allow them to be provided in a way that would not include them in the final built package, but that system is not yet in place. Unfortunately, company policy does not allow me to publish expected release dates, so all I can tell you is that we are acutely aware of that issue and plan to provide a solution at a future release.